# How to trace an another iphone inside my own app? Would i need to use icloud or gps?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gps, xcode4.2, icloud

i am starting an app in which i am tracing an iphone of another user who installed this app.
How to trace an another iphone inside my own app? Would i need to use icloud or gps? any tutorial on this?

Comment: Call your friend and ask where he is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depending on how you want to trace your userbase. Do you want to track them by location or do you want to identity them by an unique id?

You can know the location by using the `CoreLocation` framework:

> The Core Location framework lets you determine the current location or
>   heading associated with a device. The framework uses the available
>   hardware to determine the user’s position and heading. You use the
>   classes and protocols in this framework to configure and schedule the
>   delivery of location and heading events. You can also use it to define
>   geographic regions and monitor when the user crosses the boundaries of
>   those regions.

You can find more information here:
[Apple, (2011), Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

Comment: yes i am using core location framework and in its update location method i am saving the locations(latitude/longitude) of user in server side by hitting the specific url.but this will be done when user have access to internet but i want to ask that is there any other best way todo this or is its possible without internet?